# Jquery stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm developping this mobile app and I'm usint this (https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates/blob/master/template-CarouselViewApp.html) as a carousel to change through content on a page. http://jsfiddle.net/nafis56/qCkqb/

So for this I need to mess around in HTML, CSS and Jquery. Unfortonetly I'm still very green at javascript so I need your help. I changed an ID to a Class because I need to call it more than once in the same page. In the original template I refeered to, it comes as an ID. So I did this to change it:

Changed matching code on html to call it as a Class.

```
<div class="panel" title="Desiree Charms" id="desiree_charms" style="overflow: hidden;"
    data-appbuilder-object="page">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel_page">
                <h2>Desiree Charms</h2>
                <p><img src="images/desiree_charms.jpg" style="width: 85%; height: 85%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto "
                data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel_page">
                <h2>Page Two</h2>
                <p>Text and images for Page Two goes here. Swipe to go to the
                    next page.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel_dots"></div>
    </div>
```

also this on the html.

```
<script>
$.ui.autoLaunch = false;
$.ui.animateHeaders = false;       

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ui.launch();
});

$.ui.ready(function(){
    carouselSetup();
});        

function carouselSetup(){
    // set size of carousel
    $(".carousel").width($(".carousel").closest(".panel").width());
    $(".carousel").height($(".carousel").closest(".panel").height()-25);

    var options={
       vertical:false, // page up/down
       horizontal:true, // page left/right
       pagingDiv:"carousel_dots", // div to hold the dots for paging
       pagingCssName:"carousel_paging", //classname for the paging dots
       pagingCssNameSelected: "carousel_paging_selected", //classname for the selected page dots
       wrap:true //Creates a continuous carousel
    }
    var carousel = $(".carousel").carousel(options);
}
```

Changed # to . on Css.

```
.carousel {
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0 -10px;
    }

.carousel_page {
        overflow: auto; 
        -webkit-scrolling:touch;
        padding:0 10px;
    }

.carousel_dots {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        clear: both;
        position:relative;
        top:0;
        z-index:200;
    }

.carousel_paging {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #ccc;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

.carousel_paging_selected {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #000;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

.carousel h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

This is the jquery ( I didn't change anything)

```
/**
* af.web.carousel - a carousel library for App Framework apps
* @copyright 2011 - Intel
*
*/
 (function($) {
    var cache = [];
    var objId=function(obj){
    if(!obj.afmCarouselId) obj.afmCarouselId=$.uuid();
    return obj.afmCarouselId;
}
$.fn.carousel = function(opts) {
    var tmp, id;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        //cache system
        id = objId(this[i]);
        if(!cache[id]){
            tmp = new carousel(this[i], opts);
            cache[id] = tmp;
        } else {
            tmp = cache[id];
        }
    }
    return this.length == 1 ? tmp : this;
};

var carousel = (function() {
    var translateOpen =$.feat.cssTransformStart;
    var translateClose = $.feat.cssTransformEnd;

    var carousel = function(containerEl, opts) {
        if (typeof containerEl === "string" || containerEl instanceof String) {
            this.container = document.getElementById(containerEl);
        } else {
            this.container = containerEl;
        }
        if (!this.container) {
            alert("Error finding container for carousel " + containerEl);
            return;
        }
        if (this instanceof carousel) {
            for (var j in opts) {
                if (opts.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                    this[j] = opts[j];
                }
            }
        } else {

            return new carousel(containerEl, opts);
        }


            var that = this;
            af(this.container).bind('destroy', function(e){
                var id = that.container.afmCarouselId;
                //window event need to be cleaned up manually, remaining binds are automatically killed in the dom cleanup process
               window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", that.orientationHandler, false);
               if(cache[id]) delete cache[id];
               e.stopPropagation();
            });

            this.pagingDiv = this.pagingDiv ? document.getElementById(this.pagingDiv) : null;


            // initial setup
            this.container.style.overflow = "hidden";
            if (this.vertical) {
                this.horizontal = false;
            }

            var el = document.createElement("div");
            this.container.appendChild(el);
            var $el=$(el);
            var $container=$(this.container);
            var data = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.container.childNodes);
            while(data.length>0)
            {
                var myEl=data.splice(0,1);
                myEl=$container.find(myEl);
                if(myEl.get(0)==el)
                   continue;
                $el.append(myEl.get(0));
            }
            if (this.horizontal) {
                el.style.display = "block";
                el.style['float']="left";
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = "block";
            }

            this.el = el;
            this.refreshItems();
            var afEl = af(el);
            afEl.bind('touchmove', function(e) {that.touchMove(e);});
            afEl.bind('touchend', function(e) {that.touchEnd(e);});
            afEl.bind('touchstart', function(e) {that.touchStart(e);});
            this.orientationHandler = function() {that.onMoveIndex(that.carouselIndex,0);};
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", this.orientationHandler, false);

    };

    carousel.prototype = {
        wrap:true,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        dx: 0,
        dy: 0,
        glue: false,
        myDivWidth: 0,
        myDivHeight: 0,
        cssMoveStart: 0,
        childrenCount: 0,
        carouselIndex: 0,
        vertical: false,
        horizontal: true,
        el: null,
        movingElement: false,
        container: null,
        pagingDiv: null,
        pagingCssName: "carousel_paging",
        pagingCssNameSelected: "carousel_paging_selected",
        pagingFunction: null,
        lockMove:false,
        okToMove: false,

        // handle the moving function
        touchStart: function(e) {
            this.okToMove = false;
            this.myDivWidth = numOnly(this.container.clientWidth);
            this.myDivHeight = numOnly(this.container.clientHeight);
            this.lockMove=false;
            if (e.touches[0].target && e.touches[0].target.type !== undefined) {
                var tagname = e.touches[0].target.tagName.toLowerCase();
                if (tagname === "select" || tagname === "input" || tagname === "button")  // stuff we need to allow
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (e.touches.length === 1) {

                this.movingElement = true;
                this.startY = e.touches[0].pageY;
                this.startX = e.touches[0].pageX;
                var cssMatrix=$.getCssMatrix(this.el);

                if (this.vertical) {
                    try {
                        this.cssMoveStart = numOnly(cssMatrix.f);
                    } catch (ex1) {
                        this.cssMoveStart = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        this.cssMoveStart = numOnly(cssMatrix.e);
                    } catch (ex1) {
                        this.cssMoveStart = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        touchMove: function(e) {
            if(!this.movingElement)
               return;
            if (e.touches.length > 1) {
                return this.touchEnd(e);
            }

            var rawDelta = {
                x: e.touches[0].pageX - this.startX,
                y: e.touches[0].pageY - this.startY
            };

            if (this.vertical) {
                var movePos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
                this.dy = e.touches[0].pageY - this.startY;

                this.dy += this.cssMoveStart;
                movePos.y = this.dy;

                e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                if ((!this.lockMove&&isHorizontalSwipe(rawDelta.x, rawDelta.y))||Math.abs(this.dx)>5) {

                    var movePos = {x: 0,y: 0};
                    this.dx = e.touches[0].pageX - this.startX;
                    this.dx += this.cssMoveStart;
                    e.preventDefault();
                  //  e.stopPropagation();
                    movePos.x = this.dx;
                }
                else
                   return this.lockMove=true;
            }

            var totalMoved = this.vertical ? ((this.dy % this.myDivHeight) / this.myDivHeight * 100) * -1 : ((this.dx % this.myDivWidth) / this.myDivWidth * 100) * -1; // get a percentage of movement.

            if (!this.okToMove) {
                oldStateOkToMove= this.okToMove;
                this.okToMove = this.glue ? Math.abs(totalMoved) > this.glue  && Math.abs(totalMoved) < (100 - this.glue) : true;
                if (this.okToMove && !oldStateOkToMove) {
                    $.trigger(this,"movestart",[this.el]);
                }
            }

            if  (this.okToMove && movePos)
               this.moveCSS3(this.el, movePos);

        },
        touchEnd: function(e) {
            if (!this.movingElement) {
                return;
            }
            $.trigger(this,"movestop",[this.el]);
            // e.preventDefault();
            // e.stopPropagation();
            var runFinal = false;
          //  try {
                var cssMatrix=$.getCssMatrix(this.el);
                var endPos = this.vertical ? numOnly(cssMatrix.f) : numOnly(cssMatrix.e);

                if (1==2&&endPos > 0) {
                    this.moveCSS3(this.el, {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0
                    }, "300");
                } else {
                    var totalMoved = this.vertical ? ((this.dy % this.myDivHeight) / this.myDivHeight * 100) * -1 : ((this.dx % this.myDivWidth) / this.myDivWidth * 100) * -1; // get a percentage of movement.
                    // Only need
                    // to drag 3% to trigger an event
                    var currInd = this.carouselIndex;
                    if (endPos < this.cssMoveStart && totalMoved > 3) {
                        currInd++; // move right/down
                    } else if ((endPos > this.cssMoveStart && totalMoved < 97)) {
                        currInd--; // move left/up
                    }
                    var toMove=currInd;
                    //Checks for infinite - moves to placeholders
                    if(this.wrap){
                        if (currInd > (this.childrenCount - 1)) {
                            currInd = 0;
                            toMove=this.childrenCount;
                        }
                        if (currInd < 0) {
                            currInd = this.childrenCount-1;
                            toMove=-1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(currInd<0)
                            currInd=0;
                        if(currInd>this.childrenCount-1)
                            currInd=this.childrenCount-1;
                        toMove=currInd;
                    }

                    var movePos = {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0
                    };
                    if (this.vertical) {
                        movePos.y = (toMove * this.myDivHeight * -1);
                    }
                    else {
                        movePos.x = (toMove * this.myDivWidth * -1);
                    }

                    this.moveCSS3(this.el, movePos, "150");

                    if (this.pagingDiv && this.carouselIndex !== currInd) {
                        document.getElementById(this.container.id + "_" + this.carouselIndex).className = this.pagingCssName;
                        document.getElementById(this.container.id + "_" + currInd).className = this.pagingCssNameSelected;
                    }
                    if (this.carouselIndex != currInd)
                        runFinal = true;
                    this.carouselIndex = currInd;

                    //This is for the infinite ends - will move to the correct position after animation
                    if(this.wrap){
                        if(toMove!=currInd){
                            var that=this;
                            window.setTimeout(function(){
                                that.onMoveIndex(currInd,"1ms");
                            },155);
                       }
                    }
                }
            //} catch (e) {
            //    console.log(e);
           // }
            this.dx = 0;
            this.movingElement = false;
            this.startX = 0;
            this.dy = 0;
            this.startY = 0;
            if (runFinal && this.pagingFunction && typeof this.pagingFunction == "function")
                this.pagingFunction(this.carouselIndex);
        },
        onMoveIndex: function(newInd,transitionTime) {

            this.myDivWidth = numOnly(this.container.clientWidth);
            this.myDivHeight = numOnly(this.container.clientHeight);
            var runFinal = false;

                if(document.getElementById(this.container.id + "_" + this.carouselIndex))
                    document.getElementById(this.container.id + "_" + this.carouselIndex).className = this.pagingCssName;

                var newTime = Math.abs(newInd - this.carouselIndex);

                var ind = newInd;
                if (ind < 0)
                    ind = 0;
                if (ind > this.childrenCount - 1) {
                    ind = this.childrenCount - 1;
                }
                var movePos = {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                };
                if (this.vertical) {
                    movePos.y = (ind * this.myDivHeight * -1);
                }
                else {
                    movePos.x = (ind * this.myDivWidth * -1);
                }

                var time =transitionTime?transitionTime: 50 + parseInt((newTime * 20));
                this.moveCSS3(this.el, movePos, time);
                if (this.carouselIndex != ind)
                    runFinal = true;
                this.carouselIndex = ind;
                if (this.pagingDiv) {
                    var tmpEl = document.getElementById(this.container.id + "_" + this.carouselIndex);
                    if(tmpEl) tmpEl.className = this.pagingCssNameSelected;
                }

            if (runFinal && this.pagingFunction && typeof this.pagingFunction == "function")
                this.pagingFunction(currInd);
        },

        moveCSS3: function(el, distanceToMove, time, timingFunction) {
            if (!time)
                time = 0;
            else
                time = parseInt(time);
            if (!timingFunction)
                timingFunction = "linear";
            el.style[$.feat.cssPrefix+"Transform"] = "translate" + translateOpen + distanceToMove.x + "px," + distanceToMove.y + "px" + translateClose;
            el.style[$.feat.cssPrefix+"TransitionDuration"] = time + "ms";
            el.style[$.feat.cssPrefix+"BackfaceVisibility"] = "hidden";
            el.style[$.feat.cssPrefix+"TransitionTimingFunction"] = timingFunction;
        },

        addItem: function(el) {
            if (el && el.nodeType) {

                this.container.childNodes[0].appendChild(el);
                this.refreshItems();
            }
        },
        refreshItems: function() {
            var childrenCounter = 0;
            var that = this;
            var el = this.el;
            $(el).children().find(".prevBuffer").remove();
            $(el).children().find(".nextBuffer").remove();
            n = el.childNodes[0];
            var widthParam;
            var heightParam = "100%";
            var elems = [];

            for (; n; n = n.nextSibling) {
                if (n.nodeType === 1) {
                    elems.push(n);
                    childrenCounter++;
                }
            }
            //Let's put the buffers at the start/end
            if(this.wrap){
                var prep=$(elems[elems.length-1]).clone().get(0);
                $(el).prepend(prep);
                var tmp=$(elems[0]).clone().get(0);
                $(el).append(tmp);
                elems.push(tmp);
                elems.unshift(prep);
                tmp.style.position="absolute";
                prep.style.position="absolute";
            }

            var param = (100 / childrenCounter) + "%";
            this.childrenCount = childrenCounter;
            widthParam = parseFloat(100 / childrenCounter) + "%";

            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                if (this.horizontal) {
                    elems[i].style.width = widthParam;
                    elems[i].style.height = "100%";
                    elems[i].style['float']="left";
                }
                else {
                    elems[i].style.height = widthParam;
                    elems[i].style.width = "100%";
                    elems[i].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            //Clone the first and put it at the end


            this.moveCSS3(el, {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            });
            if (this.horizontal) {
                el.style.width = Math.ceil((this.childrenCount) * 100) + "%";
                el.style.height = "100%";
                el.style['min-height'] = "100%"
                if(this.wrap){
                    prep.style.left="-"+widthParam;
                    tmp.style.left="100%";
                }
            }
            else {
                el.style.width = "100%";
                el.style.height = Math.ceil((this.childrenCount) * 100) + "%";
                el.style['min-height'] = Math.ceil((this.childrenCount) * 100) + "%";
                if(this.wrap){
                    prep.style.top="-"+widthParam;
                    tmp.style.top="100%";
                }
            }
            // Create the paging dots
            if (this.pagingDiv) {
                this.pagingDiv.innerHTML = ""
                for (i = 0; i < this.childrenCount; i++) {

                    var pagingEl = document.createElement("div");
                    pagingEl.id = this.container.id + "_" + i;
                    pagingEl.pageId = i;
                    if (i !== this.carouselIndex) {
                        pagingEl.className = this.pagingCssName;
                    }
                    else {
                        pagingEl.className = this.pagingCssNameSelected;
                    }
                    pagingEl.onclick = function() {
                        that.onMoveIndex(this.pageId);
                    };
                    var spacerEl = document.createElement("div");

                    spacerEl.style.width = "20px";
                    if(this.horizontal){
                        spacerEl.style.display = "inline-block";
                        spacerEl.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    }
                    else{
                       spacerEl.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
                       spacerEl.style.display="block";
                    }

                    this.pagingDiv.appendChild(pagingEl);
                    if (i + 1 < (this.childrenCount))
                        this.pagingDiv.appendChild(spacerEl);
                    pagingEl = null;
                    spacerEl = null;
                }
                if(this.horizontal){
                    this.pagingDiv.style.width = (this.childrenCount) * 50 + "px";
                    this.pagingDiv.style.height = "25px";
                }
                else {
                    this.pagingDiv.style.height = (this.childrenCount) * 50 + "px";
                    this.pagingDiv.style.width = "25px";
                }
            }
            this.onMoveIndex(this.carouselIndex);

        }

    };
    return carousel;
})();

function isHorizontalSwipe(xAxis, yAxis) {
            var X = xAxis;
            var Y = yAxis;
            var Z = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(X,2)+Math.pow(Y,2))); //the distance - rounded - in pixels
            var r = Math.atan2(Y,X); //angle in radians
            var swipeAngle = Math.round(r*180/Math.PI); //angle in degrees
            if ( swipeAngle < 0 ) { swipeAngle =  360 - Math.abs(swipeAngle); } // for negative degree values
            if (((swipeAngle <= 215) && (swipeAngle >= 155)) || ((swipeAngle <= 45) && (swipeAngle >= 0)) || ((swipeAngle <= 360) && (swipeAngle >= 315))) // horizontal angles with threshold
            {return true; }
            else {return false}
}

})(af);
```

Now, on the CSS file when I change .carousel_dots to #carousel_dots as it was originally. The carousel starts working. The problem is I need it as a class not an ID.
I'm pretty sure the problem is in the jquery, somewhere in there I need to set carousel_dots as a class and not an ID, but where?

Any help will be much apreciated, thanks.

Comment: I see the jquery using javascripts native "getElementById" throughout it. Thats the equivalent of $("#yourtargetid") in jquery.

Comment: if you share a link of the running code, it might be easier for others to find out the problem. share your link or edit js fiddle page to share the screen. Learn Jquery, it will take 20-30mins to have basic idea. when you know the basic of Jquery, it will be easy for you to do what your are trying to do.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have to call the ID more than once in your JavaScript code. However, if you need to have more than one carousel, and therefore have more than one HTML tag with that ID, that's a problem. I always go for best practices, and because HTML with multiple tags with the same ID doesn't validate in the [W3C's validator]http://validator.w3.org/, I would just change the plugin for a carousel that takes classes instead of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is designed to trigger on HTML selectors, either elements, ID's or Class's.  It's very common for it to trigger on ID's because, as you identified, they occur once and that isolates the action to that particular item.

I know that you changed the ID's to Class's because you want to use the CSS class multiple times.  You can do this by using Class's.  But, to maintain the jQuery logic, you should not change the ID's to Class's for that purpose.  Use the ID's to synch with jQuery.  Use Class's to control your CSS.

It's difficult to advise you regarding the case you displayed because you didn't identify the initial status and exactly how you changed it.  If you can do that, we can be specific about what changes you should make.  Good luck.

Comment: how do I synch the ID if then I can only call it once in the html page? 
Isn't there a way to just change the jquery to work with a class instead of the id?

Initual status was that it worked fine, 3 dots appeared under the page of content and when i scroll right or left it paces to the next dot containing more content. But it was an id #carousel #carousel_dots and #carousel. And also the <div id> in the html. I changed all that to class and noe the dots don't appear, they just don't show on the screen.

Comment: You can have many different ID's on an HTML page, of course, and take action on any of them.  And, it's certainly true that you can fire on a class, or an element for that matter.  It's just that the jQuery logic must be designed to do that.  So, generally speaking, just changing ID's to be Class's will cause jQuery to fail unless the jQuery is designed to handle that.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to help you?